# Filter by calculated field dependent on foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x

How to filter django queryset by calculated field dependent on foreign key?

This is my models.py:

```
class RealEstate(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField()

    @property
    def is_occupied(self):
        return Agreement.objects.filter(allocated_house=self, contract_expiration_date__gte=date.today()).exists()


class Agreement(models.Model):
    allocated_house = models.ForeignKey(RealEstate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contract_expiration_date = models.DateField()
```

I need something like `RealEstate.objects.filter(is_occupied=True)`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the problem then

Comment: try RealEstate.objects.filter(agreement__contract_expiration_date__gte=date.today()).exists()

Comment: Oh, haha, really, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
RealEstate.objects.filter(agreement__contract_expiration_date__gte=date.today()).exists()
```